# Gitlab configuration postgresql service

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Just getting started with GitLab and I can't seem to get my configuration working. I'm using the following:

```
image: maven:3.3-jdk-8-alpine

stages:
  - prepare
  - build

services:
  - postgres:latest

variables:
  POSTGRES_DB: my_database
  POSTGRES_USER: runner
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: runner

prepare_db:
  stage: prepare
  image: postgres
  script:
  - export PGPASSWORD=$POSTGRES_PASSWORD
  - psql -h "postgres" -U "$POSTGRES_USER" -d "$POSTGRES_DB" -c "CREATE EXTENSION \"uuid-ossp\";"

build:
  stage: build
  script: mvn clean test
```

It works fine if I simply want to compile my code, the build would then simply be `mvn clean compile` but to run the tests I need a PostgreSQL instance. In my code I rely on UUIDs so I need to ensure that the uuid-ossp extension is installed.

In my `prepare_db` job I can connect to the Postgres instance and execute the command, I have also verified that the extension is installed properly by issuing a second script command `SELECT uuid_generate_v4();` and it returns a uuid.

When the runner gets to the `build` job it keeps telling me that the uuid_generate_v4() function is not present. Is my  `prepare_db` job being run on a different Postgres instance?

Comment: Did you double check you use the right db name in your test?

Comment: @Ekans, yup, the URL I use in my test settings is `jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/my_database`

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because prepare_db job is completely isolated from build job. So basically it doesn't prepare anything. To fix it do next steps:

```
.prepare_db: &prepare_db |
  export PGPASSWORD=$POSTGRES_PASSWORD
  psql -h "postgres" -U "$POSTGRES_USER" -d "$POSTGRES_DB" -c "CREATE EXTENSION \"uuid-ossp\";"

build:
  stage: build
  script:
  - *prepare_db 
  - mvn clean test
```